# Date time format - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe in which one of the column contains date. However the format of the date is not consistent. Have different type of date formats in the column. When I read the data in dataframe the column type is of the date column is object and I would like it to be "DATE". The sample data that I have is:

```
01/12/2022
22/02/2012
12-Jan-2023
19-10-2000
03/Feb/2021
```

As you can see the format of the data can be dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, dd-MMM-yyyy, dd/MMM/yyyy

I was using the below code to try to bring it to a standard format

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='mixed')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format = '%d-%m-%Y')
```

The above code works for most of the cases but in some cases like for 01/12/2022 it converts it into 12-01-2022. So basically the month becomes day and the day becomes month.

How do I resolve this.

Comment: Change the locale to a region where `dd-mm-yyyy` is the default

Comment: You can't.  There is no way to resolve that.  How do YOU know that it's supposed to be 1/12 and not 12/1?  You, as the human, will have to intervene and change the input data.  No computer algorithm can resolve that.

Comment: You should be able to explain the logic for when the first part is the month and when the middle part is the month.

Comment: The first part is always the date and the second part is always the month as per the source that is why I have the second line in the code df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format = '%d-%m-%Y') to standardize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is still a pattern to your data and dates are always the first you can set the `dayfirst` argument to `True` to resolve this.

read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```py
import pandas

data = {'date': ["01/12/2022", "22/02/2012", "12-Jan-2023", "19-10-2000", "03/Feb/2021", ]}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)

pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True, format="mixed")


# output 
0   2022-12-01
1   2012-02-22
2   2023-01-12
3   2000-10-19
4   2021-02-03
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note: that in the older version of pandas `format='mixed'` will not work and you'll have to set `infer_datetime_format=True` instead. But this option is Deprecated since `V2.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your date values are infact string in the source then we can use
strftime function as follows:

This issue happens a lot in excel based sources

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01/12/2022', '22/02/2012', '12-Jan-2023', '19-10-2000', '03/Feb/2021']})

# Convert the date strings to datetime objects using the infer_datetime_format parameter
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

# Change the output format of the date column to dd-mm-yyyy
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me working pass `dayfirst=True` with `format='mixed'` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True, format='mixed')
print (df)
        Date
0 2022-12-01
1 2012-02-22
2 2023-01-12
3 2000-10-19
4 2021-02-03
```